# scrapping not working Django+Apache+wsgi Production server

Tags: django, apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I developed a django app which uses `beautifulsoup4 and urllib2` to parse the data from webpages.It was working well on my development server but when I put the same on `Apache+wsgi` server, the scrapping for a data entry is very slow.It works sometime and sometime throws error  `'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`. I can't figure out why its not working on the server.When i executed the same parsing function on server in commandline, it took less than 5 secs. But why when I do a entry from django admin its not working? How should I configure the server to make it fast?

PS:Sometimes data is fetched when I make a entry.Comment if any code snippet is required

Comment: that error is a mysql error.. Could be others dbs but i'd focus there

Comment: yes its mysql error but the thing is I am not getting this error on development server...so what could be wrong on production server possibly

Comment: have to see what mysql is doing.. sounds like the scaper is going too fast for mysql to catch up. One problem is you might be using like a small VPS instance.. and your laptop is 50x more powerful

Comment: How to check this `scaper is going too fast for mysql to catch up`?Because on the server it takes 2-5 seconds for scrapping and scrapping is working fine..but the problem is somewhere with mysql

Comment: when you are getting those errors you need to debug mysql.. like `show processlist` enable slow query log...